# Terms and conditions for a simple website

Tags: website-features, terms-of-use

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a website require a privacy policy and/or terms of use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/803/when-does-a-website-require-a-privacy-policy-and-or-terms-of-use)

I finished building a website for an online chess club which I am a member of. This is my first website. The site has blogging feature so the members can log in and write blog posts and comment on other posts. The membership is limited to users of an online chess site (freechess.org) and any member of that site can join this site as well. I was wondering, is it needed to put up a terms and conditions for my new website? If so, can I have a model of that?

I searched and found some models but they are all for big sites that have e-commerce etc.

Comment: See also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-some-good-resources-for-generating-privacy-policies-and-terms-of-use?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms and Conditions really can be very customizable. It can depends on your regions, country law, and your own preferences.

Try to Google some similar website, read their T&C, take those suitable for yours, change the domain name to yours.

Sample Link:

http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1076142035&type=RESOURCES