# What do I need to write for a privacy policy page on my website?

Tags: terms-of-use, privacy-policy, problem

I am currently developing my record label's website and I'm sure I need a page on there about what information I will collect.

The website has no log ins or any interaction from the user apart from clicking page to page. I still need a privacy policy page on here though don't I as I will log statistics using various tools?

Comment: check out: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-some-good-resources-for-generating-privacy-policies-and-terms-of-use

Answer (score 1):

There are websites that generate the policy for you after filling some basic forms. [Here](http://www.generateprivacypolicy.com/) is one of them.

If there are no logins involved, you should be great with this one.

Comment: I paid for lawyer to find out I can use one of these....